# Problemas em adicionar item ao array com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: Carrinho de comprar]

Estou montando um carrinho de compras com opçoes dinâmicas com *Angularjs*.

O problema está aqui:

```js
{
    "14": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        },
        {
            "3": 1
        }
    ],
    "15": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        },
        {
            "3": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Preciso que quando adicionar o array do opcional, que a quantidade se junte a ele, 
ficando assim:

```js
{
    "14": [
        {
            "3": 1,
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        }
    ],
    "15": [
        {
            "3": 1,
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Este é o cédigo da opção:

```js
$scope.ck = function(id) {
    var oidsa = {"3": 1};
    $scope.user.roles[id].push(oidsa);
    alert($scope.user.roles[id]);
};
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código que você está usando.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem garantia de que cada item será uma lista contendo os detalhes do item no índice 0 e a quantidade no índice 1, você pode iterar entre as chaves do objeto de quantidades e inseri-las no primeiro objeto.
Algo como:

```
var items = {
  "14": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "forma": "Alface",
      "preco": 1
    },
    {
      "3": 1
    }
  ],
  "15": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "forma": "Alface",
      "preco": 1
    },
    {
      "3": 1
    }
  ]
};

var quantidades;
var quantidadesKey;

// Itera entre as chaves do objeto de items
for (var id in items) {
  // Verificação de segurança
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    quantidades = items[id][1];

    // Itera entre as chaves do objeto de quantidades
    for (quantidadesKey in quantidades) {
      // Verificação de segurança
      if (quantidades.hasOwnProperty(quantidadesKey)) {
        // Atribui o valor da quantidade na chave
        // correspondente do objeto de items
        items[id][0][quantidadesKey] = quantidades[quantidadesKey];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lembrando que isto funciona apenas caso seu objeto tenha exatamente o formato que você informou. E mais importante ainda, deve existir uma melhor solução caso você possa melhorar a estrutura destes dados.

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade **push** só funciona para arrays, para objetos ela não atribui valores. Neste caso, assuma que sua coleção seja um objeto com dois índices **14** e **15** e dentro de uma destes índices há uma camada **array** de índice **0**, que contém um objeto com **3** atributos, e que a entrada de dado para o método é uma **id**. Vamos assumir que o parâmetro passado no método seja seu índice **14** (do primeiro nível da sua coleção):

```
$scope.collection = {
    "14": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        }
    ],
    "15": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "forma": "Alface",
            "preco": 1
        }
    ]
}
$scope.ck = function(id) {
    $scope.collection[id][0]["3"] = 1;
     console.log($scope.collection[id]);
};
```

Porém para que o objeto deste array de índice 0 não fique como indefinido (undefined), já que se espera ter os mesmos atributos, quando se trata de objeto, ao criar atributos ao objeto da coleção, espera-se que haja também seus valores e que seu objeto seja usado da mesma forma em sua sequência, como foi definido em sua primeira instância de criação do atributo. E para isso é necessário passar algum valor, mesmo que seja nulo (mas isso fica sob seu critério, já que não é o problema nem a dúvida para sua questão no momento):

```
$scope.ck = function(id) {
  if ($scope.collection.length > 0) {
      angular.forEach($scope.collection, function(key, value) {
        $scope.collection[key][0]["3"] = (key == id) ? 1 : null;
      }
    console.log($scope.collection[id]); 
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um dos códigos abaixo:

```
$scope.user.roles[id]['3'] = 1;
```

ou

```
var oidsa = {"3": 1};
angular.extend( $scope.user.roles[id], oidsa );
```